# Migrate different author's content to current author

Tags: author, migration, blog

I have a blog and after several years and server exchange there are different authors' names , although only one wrote.

Can I migrate them to the current author? Any tips or ideas? Maybe with MySQL database edit?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily via dashboard.

Firstly check how many users you have in the database by going to `Users --> All users` and delete those users whom you don't in the database by clicking on delete user.

In the next step you get an option whether to delete `all the content` owned by the user(going to be deleted) or to `attribute` all the content to some other user, so in this phase select the user you want(current user).Do the same for all the users.